# Integrate the external exe in WIX UI

Tags: wix

For our product, to develop an Installer we are using WIX 3.6.

In installation sequence and as part of requiremet we need to configure some changes.This we have implemented separatley in winforms ( (treeview) and referred that exe in installation sequence. The exe is openeing perfrectly but opening in a separate window. We want to open in WIX UI itself not as a separate window.

Please provide inputs to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to launch the executable from inside the installation and integrate with the UI displayed by the package. Instead, you can launch an executable and have it register as an [External UI Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). From there you can parent the package UI to your external executable's UI.